# Converting from var to var&

Tags: c++

How can I convert a variable of type `var` or `var*` to `var&`

I've to use a function which takes an object of var class(suppose there's a class). The example code was given like this:-

```
testFunc(false, namespace1::namespace2::var(), 100);
```

in function declaration it says that the second parameter is of type `namespace1::namespace2::var&`, I can create `namespace1::namespace2::var` or `namespace1::namespace2::var*`, but how do I create `namespace1::namespace2::var&`?

I know that's too basic question but I couldn't figure it out.

**Edit:**
I've tried using just `var`, but it gives some odd errors. I am pretty sure that's some kind of fault in the function I am using. Here're the errors:-

```
Error   3   error C2825: 'CType': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
Error   4   error C2039: 'TypeCode' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
Error   5   error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'TypeCode'
Error   6   error C2065: 'TypeCode' : undeclared identifier 
Error   7   error C3203: 'CustomType' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'Base', expected a real type
```

**Edit 2**

I thought it'd be hard to answer if I include real code, since it's complicated. But have a look if it helps. The real function's signature is like this:-

```
virtual bool opRaiseEvent(bool reliable, const Common::Hashtable& parameters, nByte eventCode, nByte channelID=0, int* targetPlayers=NULL, short numTargetPlayers=NULL);
```

and the example code used the function like this:-

```
mLoadBalancingClient.opRaiseEvent(false, ExitGames::Common::Hashtable(), 100);
```

which was working fine. But now I want to add data to the HashTable, so I need to create an object of it and then pass it to the function. It's not accepting a pointer or normal variable. I don't know why it's working with just HashTable().

Comment: what is the signature of the unction you're trying to call?

Comment: Give us some real code please.

Comment: Now that you added the real error, perhaps you could also add the real code: your error talks about `CType` and  `CustomType`; no mention of `namespace1` or `var`.

Comment: What does `var()` return? by value or by reference?

Comment: It returns the const Hashtable object. I just needed to put const keyword there. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
const Common::Hashtable param = namespace1::namespace2::var();
opRaiseEvent(false, param, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot the 'const' Keyword. No need to initiate it though.

Answer (score 3):

It means the second parameter is passed by **[reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr110.htm)**. You have to simply pass:

```
namespace1::namespace2::var
```

Comment: Yeah that's the first thing I've tried. It gives some kind of odd error. May be it's the problem of the api I am using. Posting the error in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace1::namespace2::var v;
testFunc(false, v, 100);
```